Firebase Cloud Functions proper way to return
I'm writing a Cloud Function for Firebase which should change a user's password on my web app. Everything is working fine, but I was just wondering whether my code is optimized and well written, since a bad coding could cause me unexpected costs from Firebase itself.
Here is my function:
export const setNewPassword = v2.https
  .onRequest({cors: true}, async (request, response) => {
    // Se non è una richiesta POST
    if (request.method != "POST") {
      console.log("Wrong request method");
      response.status(400).send({code: "bad-request", message: "POST-required"});
      return;
    }

    // Recupero il body e lo convalido
    const body = request.body;
    if (!body) {
      console.log("Missing body");
      response.status(400).send({code: "bad-request", message: "missing-body"});
      return;
    }

    // Decifro il messaggio
    const message = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(body, "key");
    const decryptedData = JSON.parse(message.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    // Ottengo i dati
    const newPassWord = decryptedData.newPass;
    const resetCode = decryptedData.resetCode;

    // Validazione dei dati
    if (newPassWord.length < 8) {
      response.status(500).send({code: "invalid-password", message: "too-short"});
      return;
    } else if (resetCode.length != 16) {
      response.status(500).send({code: "invalid-code", message: "code-length"});
      return;
    } else {
      // Recupero il documento firestore con il codice di reset associato alla mail
      const resetDoc = await firestore.collection("password-reset")
        .where("resetCode", "==", resetCode)
        .get();

      // Validazione del documento
      // Se esiste più di un documento
      if (!resetDoc) {
        console.log(`Code '${resetCode}' not found`);
        response.status(500).send({code: "invalid-code", message: "user-not-found"});
        return;
      }

      // Se il codice è duplicato
      if (resetDoc.docs.length > 1) {
        console.log(`Code '${resetCode}' is duplicated`);
        response.status(500).send({code: "invalid-code", message: "ambiguos-code"});
        return;
      }

      // Nel caso restante esiste solo un documento
      // Recupero la mail dell'utente
      const userMail = resetDoc.docs[0].data().email;
      // Recupero l'oggetto utente
      const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userMail);
      // Aggiorno la password
      admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid, {password: newPassWord})
        .then(() => {
          // Elimino il documento con il resetCode
          resetDoc.forEach((doc) => {
            doc.ref.delete();
          });
          console.log(`User '${userMail}' updated his password`);
          response.status(200).send({result: "password-updated"});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(`Error '${error}' while updating password for user '${userMail}'`);
          response.status(500).send({error: error});
        });
    }
  });

My first concern is whether each checkpoint of the code is returning properly. I intended that an HTTPS function should terminate with a res.send(), but I noticed that if I just put it without a return after it I receive an error "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"
So, am I doing it correctly?

I've adapted your code. The main problem was that you execute an undetermined number of calls to the asynchronous delete() method in parallel, without correctly waiting that all these executions are completed. You can use Promise.all() as shown in the below code (or a Write Batch).
I removed the extra return; lines that are unecessary.
I also used await in await admin.auth().updateUser() instead of then(). These changes are identified with // <== Change here
export const setNewPassword = v2.https.onRequest(
  { cors: true },
  async (request, response) => {
    try {
      // Se non è una richiesta POST
      if (request.method != "POST") {
        console.log("Wrong request method");
        response
          .status(400)
          .send({ code: "bad-request", message: "POST-required" });
      }

      // Recupero il body e lo convalido
      const body = request.body;
      if (!body) {
        console.log("Missing body");
        response
          .status(400)
          .send({ code: "bad-request", message: "missing-body" });
      }

      // Decifro il messaggio
      const message = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(body, "key");
      const decryptedData = JSON.parse(message.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
      // Ottengo i dati
      const newPassWord = decryptedData.newPass;
      const resetCode = decryptedData.resetCode;

      // Validazione dei dati
      if (newPassWord.length < 8) {
        response
          .status(500)
          .send({ code: "invalid-password", message: "too-short" });
      } else if (resetCode.length != 16) {
        response
          .status(500)
          .send({ code: "invalid-code", message: "code-length" });
      } else {
        // Recupero il documento firestore con il codice di reset associato alla mail
        const resetDoc = await firestore
          .collection("password-reset")
          .where("resetCode", "==", resetCode)
          .get();

        // Validazione del documento
        // Se esiste più di un documento
        if (resetDoc.empty) {.   // <== Change here
          console.log(`Code '${resetCode}' not found`);
          response
            .status(500)
            .send({ code: "invalid-code", message: "user-not-found" });
        }

        // Se il codice è duplicato
        if (resetDoc.docs.length > 1) {
          console.log(`Code '${resetCode}' is duplicated`);
          response
            .status(500)
            .send({ code: "invalid-code", message: "ambiguos-code" });
        }

        // Nel caso restante esiste solo un documento
        // Recupero la mail dell'utente
        const userMail = resetDoc.docs[0].data().email;
        // Recupero l'oggetto utente
        const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userMail);
        // Aggiorno la password
        await admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid, { password: newPassWord }); // <== Change here

        const promises = []; // <== Change here

        resetDoc.forEach((doc) => {
          promises.push(doc.ref.delete()); // <== Change here
        });

        await Promise.all(promises); // <== Change here

        console.log(`User '${userMail}' updated his password`);
        response.status(200).send({ result: "password-updated" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        `Error '${error}' while updating password for user '${userMail}'`
      );
      response.status(500).send({ error: error });
    }
  }
);


Hey @AndreaMilitano, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?
